# Inheritance issues when moving from C# web to MVC App

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I usually create ASP.NET websites and have a few classes I use, mainly a `BaseClass`. Normally I would change

```
public partial class _default : Page
```

to

```
public partial class _default : BaseClass
```

with a using at the top of the namespace name. However I don't seem to be able to do this in MVC. How do I get my `BaseClass` or any other class into my MVC page?

The reason I ask is that I have a class called `errors`, I usually have this in my `global.asax` file:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
    namespace.errors.WriteError(Request.Url.ToString(), objErr.Message);
}
```

But I seem unable to do this, even with a shared namespace across the whole site

It is most probable that this question is lame but whatever :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the base class You can create ApplicationControler
Somethig like :

```
namespace YourApplication.Controllers
{
    public abstract class ApplicationController : Controller
    {
        public ApplicationController()
        {
            using(ApplicationDataContext menu = new ApplicationDataContext())
            {
                // loading data for menu control
                MenuRepository myMenu = new MenuRepository();
                ViewData["menu"] = myMenu.MenuList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can just extend it from any controler
like this:

```
namespace YourApplication.Controllers
{
    public class DefaultController : ApplicationController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice in my example in application controler I am loading view that I am gonna display on every single page, and you can load anything you want, anything that you need often or always. Thats pretty much your base class.

Comment: thanks very much, thats quite a nice idea, there is quite a lot to learn really fast for the MVC stuff and this will be sure to help alot

Comment: Yes, it is quite nice idea to have application controler, in case of this example I am actually displaying the ViewData["menu"] in the master page trough mvc user control (partial). And you of course can have variables and what not.